# Div element slides down from the top of the html body when applying CSS transition

Tags: html, css

I'm a beginner at html/css and I'm facing a little problem when applying transitions to a div element.
When I hover the mouse over my div element, I want it to smoothly change its background-color from red to black.

Here is my html and css code:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.exemplo1 {
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  transition: all 1s linear;
  -moz-transition: all 1s linear;
  -o-transition: all 1s linear;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s linear;
}

.exemplo1:hover {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>Página de Teste</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="transicoes.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="normalize.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="exemplo1"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

This is the result:
https://youtu.be/5whZpt0YR68

The color changing works exactly as I expected, but as soon as the html file opens, my div element slides down from the top of the html body until it settles at its final position (I wasn't expecting the slide down part). This is happening at Google Chrome, Opera and Microsoft Edge, but not at Firefox.

Would you guys have any idea of why this is happening?

Comment: I turned your code into a snippet and it works fine. Remove normalize.css to see if that might be what is causing the issue. Alternatively, instead of “all” transition “background-color” instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change this part in your `CSS`:

```
transition: all ...
```

to

```
transition: background-color ...
```

For example:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.exemplo1 {
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
}

.exemplo1:hover {
  background-color: black;  
  transition: background-color 1s linear;
  -moz-transition: background-color 1s linear;
  -o-transition: background-color 1s linear;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 1s linear;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>Página de Teste</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="transicoes.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="normalize.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="exemplo1"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

You can achieve an even better optical effect with a little bit of `Javascript` also. For example:

```js
let exemplo = document.querySelector('.exemplo1');

exemplo.addEventListener('mouseover', (e) => {
e.target.classList.remove('out_exemplo1');
});

exemplo.addEventListener('mouseout', (e) => {
e.target.classList.add('out_exemplo1');
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.out_exemplo1 {
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  transition: background-color 1s linear;
  -moz-transition: background-color 1s linear;
  -o-transition: background-color 1s linear;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 1s linear;
  background-color: red;
}
.exemplo1 {
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
}

.exemplo1:hover {
  background-color: black;  
  transition: background-color 1s linear;
  -moz-transition: background-color 1s linear;
  -o-transition: background-color 1s linear;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 1s linear;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>Página de Teste</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="transicoes.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="normalize.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="exemplo1"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Peter! After I changed the transition-property from all to background-color it stoped sliding down. But now, I also changed the transition duration from 1s to 5s, and I realized my div is emerging from blank to red when the html file opens.This was already happening when I first sent the question, but the transition duration was so short that I haven't noticed. Would you know why is it happening? Best regards!

Comment: @RianMiranda the edit should clear the problem. This happens because transition property is not inside the `:hover` `CSS`.

Comment: @RianMiranda quickly hover over and out of the `.exemplo1` element in the second snippet after the edit. I think this is a much smoother visual effect that is applied to the element.

Answer (score 0):

Remove extra css files added that should be effecting it.

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}

.exemplo1 {
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 100px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: red;
    transition: all 1s linear;
    -moz-transition: all 1s linear;
    -o-transition: all 1s linear;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s linear;
}

.exemplo1:hover {
    background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Página de Teste</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="exemplo1"></div>
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Deeksha! I've tried it before sending the question. Unfortunately, it didn't worked.